# Bootstrap Wont show button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have started to learn Bootstrap today and i wanted to ask few Questions.

I have been trying to make the button on this code show, Only it doesnt Respond accordingly. As it does not show the button clearly.

Code looks like this.

```
<?php include 'header.php'
?>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="col-md-12" >
    <div class ="page-header">
    <h1>This is a Test header</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="col-md-12">
    <form name="samris" id="samris" method="post" action="hamish.php"/>
    <table class ='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

    <div class ="form-group">
    <label for "firstname"> First Name :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" />
    </div>

    <div class ="form-group">
    <label for "firstname"> Last Name :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" />
    </div>

    <div class ="form-group">
   <select class="form-control"id="" name="">
   <option>Please Select</option>
   <option>List 1</option>
   <option>List 1</option>
   <option>List 1</option>
    </div>


    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your `<select>` field.

Comment: Merci. I am very grateful, Thank you.